# Firestore - Store a property id is reference type by firestore Batch transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I trying to store data content reference type by batch transaction, then I got an exception:

> Function WriteBatch.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in document orders/OC9dZErupEhPsamp8QEd)

Is there a way we can use batch transaction to store reference type?

this is my code:

```
batch.update(orderRef, {
    userId: firestore.doc(userId),
});
```

Comment: Can you share complete code so we can see where firestore is defined and where are you using `batch.set()` ?

Comment: this is my code: 
```import firebase from "firebase/app";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({});
const firestore = app.firestore();
const batch = firestore.batch();
batch.update(orderRef, {
     userId: firestore.doc(userId),
});```

Comment: I also post my question on github https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6057

Comment: That's still not complete code. I still can't see firestore being declared.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hoangdevelopers/3339090aeb24d4b484456945d75df008
and https://gist.github.com/hoangdevelopers/69b8ba34ece959d17a080b6f2e35f16b

Answer (score 0):

Normaly update() use to update existing firestore data. [Review firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for the same. In that given example they are updating population by increments of value or with new population number but before passing it in each update function values are stored in one cost value if it is not static value. as Asked by @dharmaraj please edit your questions by posting with full code you can also read given firestore documentation for your own studies.

```
    import firebase from "firebase/app";  
    const app = firebase.initializeApp({});
     const firestore = app.firestore(); 
    const batch = firestore.batch(); 
    const newUserId = firestore.doc(userId);
    batch.update(orderRef, {
     userId: newUserId,
    });
```

Log newUserId value and see what are you getting into it.

Comment: Yeah I agree that update() is a function use to update existed data, but it's not a problem. the main issue is I want to store "newUserId" as a reference type, if I use firestore (without batch) to store a reference type, I can do it, but not with batch transaction

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hoangdevelopers/3339090aeb24d4b484456945d75df008
this is my code
https://gist.github.com/hoangdevelopers/69b8ba34ece959d17a080b6f2e35f16b

Answer (score 0):

You can't store the reference object that `doc()` returns, it's an object that may have circular references and functions in it. `doc()` is not the id of the document. If you want to get the id (which is a string), then:

```
const newUserId = firestore.doc(userId).ref.id;
batch.update(orderRef, {
 userId: newUserId,
});
```

Comment: no, it is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why batch validate input should be a pure object. I tried to push reference type id inside nested object then it work well, yeah I know it already is a trick, but it work.

change:

```
batch.update(docRef, {
  user: firestore.collection('users').doc(userId)
})
```

to:

```
batch.update(docRef, {
  user: {
    id: firestore.collection('users').doc(userId)
  }
})
```